# My browser doesn't load my images and js files in my symfony project

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have a symfony project but the browser fail to load images and js files.
Here is how i call my js and images

```
<img width="300" src="{{ asset('assets/images/logos/logo.png') }}">

<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/Temp/iCheck/icheck.min.js') }}"></script>
```

and here is my assetic in config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
        plugins_css:
            inputs:
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/css/AdminLTE.min.css'
        plugins_js:
            inputs:
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js'
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/js/app.min.js'
                - '@TemplateBundle/Resources/assets/js/dashboard.js'
```

But the project works fine in the internet Explorer but not in chrome or Mozilla. have anyone faced the same problem ? am i missing something

Comment: which file is beeing called when you run IE, vs when you run a diff browser,  and what is the responsecode of the 'failed' image, just a 404 or something else ?

Comment: the response  for the failed image is just failed to load response data. when i run IE it calls everyfile (js , css) files and images But in the other browses it gave me a canceled status for the same js, css files

Comment: is the same path beeing generated and called by assetic, in both browsers?

Comment: Yes the same path is generated by both browsers

Comment: Do you have a server cache enabled? I once had this issue, and the problem was simply the server cache (zend opcache in my case). So even after clearing Symfony cache, server cache prevented me to see any modifications

Comment: i disabled the server cache but i still have the same issue :/